# What are the best no-code or low-code platforms for creating apps closely integrated with Meta services?

Tags: web-apps, software-development, web-development, facebook

I want to create a small web application for managing a doctor's office as MVP. My doctor doesn't have precise requirements, but she communicates extensively via Meta services (Facebook and Instagram) and uses Google Calendar.

I am looking for a no-code or low-code platform with built-in integration in Meta (and Google services) that allows me to improve her communication experience with minimum coding.

Comment: 1. I have no clue what MVP is. 2. A doctor is using social media for medical issues/patient correspondence? On what planet is that legal. The security implications are horrendous.

Comment: @Tetsujin
1 MVP - Minimum Viable Product
2 I am from Ukraine. We have many internally displaced persons and refugees in other countries because of Russia's attack on our country. Doctors are actively using messengers (Facebook, Instagram, WhatsApp, Viber) to consult new or chronically ill patients and write electronic prescriptions. AFAIK, big clinics have dedicated software for online communication with patients. I am looking for an independent doctor solution.

Comment: There are already a few opensource Medical apps like OpenEMR (https://sourceforge.net/projects/openemr/) and GNUHealth (https://www.gnuhealth.org/download.html) that you can look at. Not sure if now has the integration you need. But it may be easier for you to adopt one of them, and build the integration required. I have some experience setting up OpenEMR in the past.